# Jquery Validation for Driver Registration HTML Form

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-validate

Hi make one html from which submitting without refresh by jquery. Problem is that I am beginner and I dont know how to add validation for html form. I need changes in script so first form will validate by jquery or ajax then it will submit by jquery witout page refresh.. have look in my code. Please provide me working solution in that first form validate by ajax jquery then submit by jquery without refresh.. Thanks in advance

JQUERY:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#form").submit(function() {
    // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
var uno = $("#uno").val();
var name = $("#name").val();
var licence = $("#licence").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var phone = $("#phone").val();
var dataString =  'uno=' + uno + '&name=' + name + '&licence=' + licence + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone;


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "addd.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(){
                 $('form#form').hide(function(){$('div.success').fadeIn();});
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML FORM:

```
<form id="form" method="post" name="form" action=""> 
              <fieldset id="opt">

                        <legend>Driver Information</legend>

                        <label for="choice">Name : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value=""> <br />
                        <label for="choice">Licence No : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="licence" name="licence" value=""> <br />
                        <label for="choice">Email : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value=""> <br />
                        <label for="choice">Phone : </label>
                        <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" value=""> <br />


                       <input type="hidden" name="uno" id="uno" value="" /> 
                        <br />
                         </fieldset>
                      <div align="center">

                       <input id="button2" type="submit" value="Add Driver" />  
                      <input id="button2" type="reset" />
                      </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: there are multiple mistakes in your html form also.. anyways tell me do u want to validate all the form input field??

Answer (score 0):

I found multiple errors/mistakes on your HTML form too. some of them I want to mention..

- `for` attribute of `label` have same value of the next input/select id, read:

  #### http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp
- Dont assign *name* for `name` and `id` attribute, it's misleading.( good practice)
- Don't write `value =""`, if you there is no initial value of any input box.
- If u want to validate a hidden field then write some value for that on form intialization, otherwise it wud be always empty and your validation never works.
- If u want to validate all input field together for emptyness then use `:input` selector ,read :

  #### http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/
- Don't forget to validate  email address
- If you want to post a form via ajax then there is no need to write `method` and `action` attribute in your form
- Your reset button shoud have some value, otherwise its takes default value.

---

A very useful and handy article for newbie for jquery ajax validation

#### http://jorenrapini.com/blog/css/jquery-validation-contact-form-with-modal-slide-in-transition

OR  you can use jquery validator plugin :

#### http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

here is your neat and clean form

```
<form id="driverForm" name="driverForm"> 
    <fieldset id="opt">
        <legend>Driver Information</legend>
        <label for="lname">Name : </label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" > <br />
        <label for="licence">Licence No : </label>
        <input type="text" id="licence" name="licence" ><br />
        <label for="email">Email : </label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" ><br />
        <label for="phone">Phone : </label>
        <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" > <br />
        <input type="hidden" name="uno" id="uno"  /><br />
    </fieldset>
    <div align="center">
        <input type="submit"  id="submitForm" name="submitForm" value="Add Driver" />  
        <input type="reset" value="clear" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Hope this will be useful for you.

### UPDATE

put it insdie `submit()` and before `ajax` like this

```
$("form").submit(function() {
if($('#lname').val() == '')
            return false;
});

$.ajax({
```

**NOTE:** dont create `dataString` Manually there is inbuilt function in jQuery.

### [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Please note that ,*this is not matter that your form is submitting or not. most thing is it a valid form or not.*

Happy to help :)

Comment: Hi My form is working fine with JQUERY .. I just want to intigrate validation with current jquery script.. want to validate name licence no email and phone. before form submit... Form is working fine When I submit it with jquery its submited without refresh and data inserted in mysql.. Problem only that I dont know where I have to put validation code in script which validate the form and if validation return true then form will submit by $.ajax... I need like that ( I am beginner so Complicated code out of my understanding so if possible provide me just working code example for above script)

Comment: @user i think you are not worried about your HTML mistakes. this is really .... anyways see my update part ..this will helps u.Thanks

Comment: thanks to help me I will test it and come back to you if more help required :)